# how to delete the recycler view item using retrofit or volley?

Tags: android, android-volley, retrofit

I want to delete the recyclerview item using retrofit or volley network library. Please post the code or example?

Comment: What exactly do you mean, delete a recycler view item using Retrofit, a networking library?

Comment: @Aenadon.Yes delete a recycler view item using retrofit library.

Comment: But retrofit is a networking library

Comment: retrofit has nothing to do with recyclerview, retrofit does network operations

Comment: @Aenadon.My data is coming from json.Can we use volley for delete the item.

Comment: Are you trying to say that in your app you did a rest call to an API and you have to update the recycler view?

Comment: Again retrofit/volley has nothing to do with recyclerview, take the data you get from them and create logic to add/remove whatever you need from the recyclerview yourself

Comment: @Android storm.Yes, i did a rest API call. I want to update and delete the recycler view with rest API

Comment: @lavi let me know if you need more details. I hope that works for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - notifyDataSetChange from within custom ArrayAdapter class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638321/android-notifydatasetchange-from-within-custom-arrayadapter-class)

Comment: @lavi Can you please close the question? In the case that the solution provided fix your issue?

Answer (score 2):

*Firstable you do not have to remove the items on the RecyclerView. The main idea is provide the List of item, set it in the Adapter and load again the RecyclerView on the UI. If you have a RestCall using Retrofit all you have to do is:*

Create an Update method and call it every time you need to show the changes on the UI. This method will do the RetrofitCall and it will give the List of items you need to pass to the adapter using a custom listener with the return onSuccess.

```
private RecyclerAdapter updateRecycler() {
    getItemsFromApi(new RestApiListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<Items> items) {
            recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, items);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String message) {
            showError(message);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is how to do the CallBack in Retrofit with the listener

```
public Callback<Items> getItemsFromApi(final RestApiListener listener) {
    return new Callback<Items>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Items> call, Response<Items> response) {
            switch (response.code()) {
                case 200:
                    listener.onSuccess(response.body().getItems());
                    break;
                default:
                    listener.onError("Error " + response.message());
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Items> call, Throwable t) {
            listener.onError(t.getMessage().toString());
        }
    };
}

public interface RestApiListener  {
    void onSuccess(List<Items> items);

    void onError(String s);
}
```

Also [here is an example code](https://github.com/williamgdev/Retrofit).